# How do you open an SDF database file in SQL Server Object Explorer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sql-server-ce

I have created database using EF6 code first but can not figure out how to open sdf database file in **SQL Server Object Explorer**. Connection string: "Data Source=|DataDirectory|AlgebraDB.sdf". 
*Using Visual Studio 2017.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot open a SQL Server Compact (.sdf) database file in SQL Server Object Explorer. In Visual Studio 2017, install the SQLite and SQL Server Compact Toolbox extension, and use that to open and explore the file (I am the author of the Toolbox)

Comment: Very userful tool. Thank you!